# Run my executable automatically as root ubuntu

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu

I am working in Ubuntu 14.04 I have an C++ application which I have compiled. I get the executable which name is "program". Well the thing is that this program use opencv and sockets then if I try to execute it in the terminal like this:

```
./program
```

I got this error:

```
listener: socket: Operation not permitted
setsockopt: Bad file descriptor
```

This error appear because I using socket and I need to run my application as root, so I tyoe this:

```
sudo ./program
```

This request my password and the program works propertly.

The thing is that I want to run this "program" automatically when I start my Ubuntu, but it does not work. I have another application the name is "camera" which only use opencv, no socket, then I do not need to run as root. So I put this application in the startup application of ubuntu and the "camera" application start at the begining without problem.

So I guess that my problem is that I need to run as root my "program", but I can not get it.

Someone could help me?

Many Thanks

Comment: You could configure `/etc/sudoers`, or start your program thru `crontab`, or in your init scripts.

Comment: You could use a port that doesn't require root permissions to listen to.

Comment: Thanks I configured the /etc/souders, and I can run it without sudo but I still got the socket error

Comment: It would be better if you try to use non-privileged ports (>= 1024) then you won't need to be root

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the ownership of the program to root:root and use the setuid permission so that it runs with the permissions of its owner, not the user who invoked it.

```
sudo chown root:root ./program
sudo chmod a+s ./program
```

Now the program will run with root privileges for all users.

Hope that helps.

Side note: As a programmer you should strive to ensure that programs that run with root privileges are free of security holes, so that they're not vulnerable to buffer overflow exploits, etc.

Comment: "Side note" can't be emphasized enough. If your program has any sort of buffer overflow, or uses a library (e.g. libc) that has one,  then your system is owned.  If it's at all possible, redesign your program so that it can run as a non-root user (perhaps with special permissions).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer the thing is that when I run the program apeear this Gtk-WARNING **: This process is currently running setuid or setgid.
This is not a supported use of GTK+. You must create a helper
program instead. For further details, see

Comment: I am reading something about, and GTK is not a security hole, so you are right, but how could I solved my problem?

Comment: You could split your project into two programs - with just one of them running as root - and communicate between the two processes using domain sockets or pipes.

Comment: I using the sockets because I am using RecvRawEth.c for get ethernet data and I am using opencv for process video. Then my question is, if I have this program how can I run this at the begining in automatic way? or is it no possible?